# scatter plot : change distance in X-axis with multiple variable

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to plot some numeral Data with scatter plot. I used the following code to plot the Data as a scatter with using the same axes for the different variables.

```
library(car)
data("Anscombe")
mydat <- melt(Anscombe,"urban")
ggplot(mydat,aes(value,urban ))+geom_point() + 
     facet_grid(.~variable)+geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F)
```

here is the plot, and the range of x-axis value are the same for three variables. I can not see the points of variable educations very well.
[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hN3Z.png)

so i try to change the range of x-axis. Below are the code.

```
ggplot(mydat,aes(value,urban ))+geom_point() + 
facet_grid(.~variable)+ geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F)+
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,450), ylim = NULL, expand = TRUE)
```

Now the I can see the value of variable education. but the value of income is gone, because the value of  income is > 450.
[plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEMxb.png)

how can i change the x-axis value of each variables instead of change all? I would be grateful if anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the additional argument `scales = "free"`:

```
ggplot(mydat, aes(value, urban)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ variable, scales = "free") + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]